# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble._bagging'

Tags: github, data-science, python-3.7, data-science-experience, github-issues

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble._bagging'

Which version is suitable of `scikit` learn for the above error?

I am facing this issue when I am using the python 3.7 version. And I can't update the version.

Comment: I don't think there is any version of `scikit-learn` which contains `sklearn.ensemble._bagging`. You can check the API of `sklearn.ensemble`  [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/support.html#documentation-resources) with any version.